# Getting wrong output

Tags: c++

This is the code: 
A[0] (in the main function) should be equal to 0, not 1. I can't find my mistake. I suppose the problem is somewhere in the and1 function, but again, I can't seem to be able to find it. Anyway I am pretty sure that the first sentence covered the problem pretty well, but the website is forcing me to write more information.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// V and ^ or
using namespace std;
int A[] = {0, 1, 1};
int B[] = {1, 0, 1};

 int* and1(int A[], int B[])
{
    int ret[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] == 1 && B[i] == 1 )
        {
            ret[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ret[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int* or1(const int A[], const int B[])
{
    int ret[] = {0 ,0 ,0};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] == 1 || B[i] == 1)
        {
            ret[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ret[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int* a = and1(A, B);
    int* b = or1(A, B);
    if(*(a+1) == *(b+1))
    {
        cout << a[0] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you can't find your mistake, then do debug

Comment: you returns pointer to local array in or1 and and1

Comment: Why don't you pass the resultant array as the third param and store the result in it and return void? That is change the prototype to void and1(int * A, int * B, int * ret) and same for or1. This will ensure that the changes you make are stored in the resultant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning pointers to arrays which are local to the function and these local arrays  do not exist when the function scope `{  }` ends. What you get is a pointer pointing to something that does not exist and an **Undefined behavior**.

Comment: That explains everything. Thank you. I will select this as an answer (Aftere 10 minutes or so when the system will let me) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`int ret[3];` in function `and1` is a variable local to `and1`. When `and1` completes execution, it goes out of scope. So returning its address does not make sense.
Instead, you could pass the `ret` array to `and1` (similarly for or1), with the prototype being:

```
void and1(const int A[], const int B[], int ret[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer of a temporary array from function `and1`. And the result is undefined.

```
int* and1(int A[], int B[])
{
   int ret[3];
   //...
   return ret;
}

int* a = and1(A, B); // <-- Undefined behavior
```

After `return ret`, the array`ret` destroys and it doesn't mean more to use.